# getting node items by taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I can get a list of node items by content type, using the following query:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
    $query->condition('n.status', NODE_PUBLISHED);
    $query->condition('n.type', 'slider');
    $nids = $query
        ->fields('n', array('nid'))
        ->orderBy('changed', 'DESC')
        ->range(0, 4)
        ->addTag('node_access')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchCol();
    $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
```

I want to filter this output further with taxonomy. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`EntityFieldQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) instead of the `SelectQuery` that `db_select` uses. You should do something like this:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$result = $query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node', '=')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'slider', '=')
  ->fieldCondition('fieldname', 'tid', $tid)
  ->propertyOrderBy('changed', 'DESC')
  ->range(0, 4)
  ->addTag('node_access')
  ->execute();
```

The results will be an array of objects containing the nid and vid.

Read more about the [`fieldCondition`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3AfieldCondition/7)

Comment: Sorry but i am a newbie in drupal. Can you add complete code to get the array of node items filtered with taxonomy?

Comment: @askkirati what you need to put in the fieldCondition depends on how you set up your field, it's name etc.

Comment: What will i have to do if i have to get taxonomy named slider with term slider1

Comment: @askk what matters is not what you named the vocabulary but what you named the field. Usually it will have a name of "field_..."

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;

$entities = $query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node', '=')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'slider', '=')
  ->propertyCondition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED, '=')
  ->fieldCondition($field, 'tid', $tid, '=')
  ->propertyOrderBy('changed', 'DESC')
  ->range(0, 4)
  ->addTag('node_access')
  ->execute();

$nodes = entity_load('node', array_keys($entities['node']));
```

`$field` contains the name of the taxonomy term field; `$tid` is the taxonomy term ID for which the list of nodes is filtered.

Comment: what will be the value of $tid?

Comment: `$tid` contains the taxonomy term ID; if you need to filter the list of nodes basing on the vocabulary ID used for the nodes, then the query is slightly different.

Comment: This solution seems to work too. But i think both does the same thing